yarn cache is not found in github actions
this is my config in github actions
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@0ad4b8fadaa221de15dcec353f45205ec38ea70b # v4.1.4
      - uses: actions/setup-node@60edb5dd545a775178f52524783378180af0d1f8 # v4.0.2
        with:
          node-version: 20
          cache: yarn
          cache-dependency-path: "yarn.lock"
      - run: yarn install --immutable

but I keep getting yarn cache is not found. any idea what's going on?
since the cache is unavailable the job automatically uses the yarn classic instead of picking the right one from yarn lock which is yarn 4

An alternative could be to try using the actions/cache instead of the setup-node to manage your yarn cache
